# buildspec with aws codeartifact with MVN

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codeartifact

I have been searching a lot for getting a sample buildspec where integrates the codeartifacts with mvn.

here is my buildpsec is,
following is my doubts.

1. since we cannot create a setting.xml where aws tells us to mention the servers, mirrors, profile and token, how can we upload the dependencies to the artifact repository.
2. my goal is to put only the resultant jar not the .m2/* all dependency in the artefact repository, moreover is it a good approach ?

`buildspec file`

```
version: 0.2 
phases: 
  install: 
    runtime-versions: 
      java: openjdk8 
    commands: 
      - pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user 
      - export CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain $DOMAIN --domain-owner $ACCOUNT_ID --query authorizationToken --output text` 
  build: 
    commands: 
      - echo Build started on `date` 
      - mvn package 
artifacts: 
  type: zip 
  files: 
    - '/target/launcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' 
cache: 
  paths: 
    - '/root/.m2/**/*'.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> since we cannot create a setting.xml where aws tells us to mention the servers, mirrors, profile and token, how can we upload the dependencies to the artifact repository.

In fact, you can. You were on the right track.
`mvn` will not execute until the `build` phase, so in `install` you can edit its settings, including `settings.xml`. The easiest is to replace them altogether:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - cp ./codebuild-maven-settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
```

You can then use your `CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN` environment variable in the custom `settings.xml` file.

In order for this solution to work you need to put the `codebuild-maven-settings.xml` file at the root of your repository. This might not be the most elegant and if you want to truely make this as smooth as possible, I recommend putting the file on S3 and downloading it first.